# Can I have same WordPress theme name as an existing one?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, naming

I came up with a good name(as I thought) for a WordPress theme that I want to create. Unfortunately, I found another WP theme using the same name after googled it. My theme will be free and only available on my own site. I really like the name.
Can I have same WordPress theme name as an existing one?

Comment: I'd change your name slightly. Avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

There are many themes out there with similar/identical names just from the sheer amount of themes available, e.g. http://themeforest.net/ has many themes with the same names created by different people.

However there will likely be some drawbacks to doing so. For example it will be harder to differentiate between your theme and theirs, if their theme is already successful then people searching for your theme will likely find the other theme in the search results instead.